# Credit Card type function shows onlu default

Tags: javascript, html, credit-card

I want to show the type of the card when writing card number in the input. I wrote some function, but it only shows default. I also want the picture of visa and mastercard show when two first digits are equal to their norm.

HTML: (the crosses are the number)

```
 <div class="imgs" id="card-brand">
            <img src="./images/chip.png" width="50px" />
            <img src="./images/visa.png" width="70px" id="visa"/>
            <!-- <img src="./images/mastercard.png" width="70px" id="mastercard"/> -->
          </div>
          <ul id="snum">
            <li>
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
              <span class="cross"
                ><label class="star">#</label
                ><label class="label">1</label></span
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
```

JS (the card number changing when typing function):

```
function cardNumber(c){
    const numberLabel = document.querySelectorAll(".label"); 
    const cross = document.querySelectorAll(".cross");
    const num = c.value; 
    
    if (num.length <= 16){
    
    for(let j = 0;j<numberLabel.length;j++){
        numberLabel[j].innerHTML = "#";
        cross[j].classList.remove("active"); 
      } 
     for(let i = 0;i<num.length;i++){
        numberLabel[i].innerHTML = num[i];
        cross[i].classList.add("active"); 
      }
        
    }else{
        c.value = num.substring(0,16);
    } 
}
```

JS (for the card type):

```
function cardType(c) {
    let number = document.querySelector('#snum');
    number = number.toString();
    let re = new RegExp("^4");
    if (number.match(re) !== null) return "visa";

    re = new RegExp("^5[1-5]");
    if (number.match(re) !== null) return "mastercard";

    return "default"; // default type
}
```

How to fix the card type and add images changing thing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you meant with the crosses but here's a basic implementation of a system you described, maybe you can use this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        .container {
            max-width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 150px;
        }

        .cardImages {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 150px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 36px;
        }
    
        input {
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
    </style>
<head>
    <title>Credit Card Type Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Credit Card Type Checker</h1>
        <input type="text" id="cardNumber" placeholder="Enter your credit card number...">
        <div class="cardImages">
            <img src="visa.png" id="visaImage">
            <img src="mastercard.jpg" id="mastercardImage">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    const cardNumber = document.getElementById('cardNumber');
    const visaImage = document.getElementById('visaImage');
    const mastercardImage = document.getElementById('mastercardImage');
    
    visaImage.style.display = 'none';
    mastercardImage.style.display = 'none';

    cardNumber.addEventListener('input', () => {
        const value = cardNumber.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        if (/^4/.test(value)) {
            visaImage.style.display = 'block';
            mastercardImage.style.display = 'none';
        } else if (/^5[1-5]/.test(value)) {
            mastercardImage.style.display = 'block';
            visaImage.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            visaImage.style.display = 'none';
            mastercardImage.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}
</script>
```